# Allow lack of space after function parenthesis if there is a return type hint in PHP (CodeSniffer)

Tags: php, php-7, phpcodesniffer

I am using the [MediaWiki coding standard](https://packagist.org/packages/mediawiki/mediawiki-codesniffer) for `php_codesniffer`. Thing is, that is created for PHP version `<7.0.0`. Let's take the following not-formatted code snippet:

```
function test(){}
```

The sniffer will report an error, that is needs space between `)` and `{` (the rule is `Generic.Functions.OpeningFunctionBraceKernighanRitchie.SpaceAfterBracket`)
Now that's ok, it is normal (for me at least) to write

```
function test() {}
```

But when it comes to PHP 7 and the function has a return type hint, I want it formatted like this

```
function test(): string {}
```

So no space between `)` and `:`, but spaces between `string` and other tokens there. What is the rule I have to write to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is already sniff for that in Slevomat/CodingStandard: https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard/blob/master/README.md#slevomatcodingstandardtypehintstypehintdeclaration-

It is high quality package I use for over a year. They also have a branch for 3.0 ready. Also check also sniffs, they're awesome and helps with refactoring to PHP 7.0 and 7.1.